# Hurwitz numbers and Frobenius manifolds

Tags: enumerative-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Generating functions of the Gromov-Witten invariants (as well as some other important partition functions) are known to be related to the Frobenius manifold structure. Are there any Frobenius manifolds behind generating functions of simple (double, multiple) Hurwitz numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There are Frobenius algebras in the story.  see

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1273v1.pdf